# Locomotive CMS undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, locomotivecms

I am trying to get Locomotive CMS setup and running locally but I am running into this error:

```
NoMethodError in Locomotive/pages#index

Showing /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc4/app/views/locomotive/pages/_page.html.haml where line #4 raised:

undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: - if page.not_found?
2:   %li.sep &nbsp;
3: 
4: %li{ :id => "item-#{page.id}", :class => "page #{css_for_page(page)}" }
5: 
6:   - children = can?(:manage, page) ? page.children : page.children.find_all { |p| !p.templatized? }
7:
```

Anyone else run into this issue with Locomotive?

Locomotive Gem: `gem 'locomotive_cms', '~> 2.0.0.rc.4', :require => 'locomotive/engine'`

I was able to get the administrator user setup, but when you get done with the initial setup, the app redirects you to /locomotive/pages and then I get that error

Answer (score 3):

In locomotive's documentation they state to do the following in your Gem file:
`gem 'locomotive_cms', '~> 2.0.0.rc4', :require => 'locomotive/engine'`

But you actually have to do the following:
`gem 'locomotive_cms', :require => 'locomotive/engine', :git => "git://github.com/locomotivecms/engine.git"`